# VB 2010 Extract customer name in filenpath string using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, extract, filepath

I was given this code for extracting just the job number out of the filepath.  I don't know how to use regex properly from what examples I've found, but I'd like to be able to extract just the "blah_blah" portion of the filename now. I'd appreciate any tips or suggestions.

Example filepath: Q:\2463_Customer_Name....\

I'd like to just get 'Customer Name' for my string.

```
Dim numRegex As New Regex("\d+") 
Dim number As String = numRegex.Match("Q:\2456_blah_blah\file.txt").Value
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about using RegExes in VB.net, but a string like

```
^[A-Z]:\\[0-9]{0,4}_(.+)\\.*$
```

should provide a good starting point. The backslashes are escaped with backslashes ;). What exactly determines the starting and ending of the blah_blah part? I guess it is the underscore and the trailing \ ?
In my regex example the () contains the blah_blah.

```
^ start of line
[A-Z] one upper case letter
:\\ followed by a colon and a backslash
[0-9]{0,4} followed by up to four digits between 0-9 (tweaking here might be necessary)
_ followed by an underscore
(.*) followed by at least one (+) arbitrary character
\\ followed by a backslash (again, escaped maybe you don't need this)
.*$ followed by any number of characters until the end of the line ($)
```

If you know more about the pattern you should consider editing your question to be more clear. Are there only letters in the blah_blah part, etc.

Comment: well the starting point will always be "drive letter:\four numbers_start here...     The end point will be the second backslash '\' of the filename.  Yes there are typically only letters.  My appologies for the title it was edited by another.

Comment: I tried that bit of code, but it gives me the entire length of the filepath.  Since there is a predefined starting point, Could I just chop off the first 8 characters then take the next characters to string until it reaches the next backslash?

Comment: try numRegex.Match("^[A-Z]:\\[0-9]{0,4}_(.+)\\.*$").Groups(1)
As said, I have no clue about VB.net